# How can I convert ESRI personal geodatabase (.mdb) to shapefile using OGR in C#?

Tags: shapefile, c#, ogr2ogr, personal-geodatabase

I have to create a class in C# in which I would like to insert a function that converts an ESRI personal geodatabase, extracting that features it contains in shp using OGR. I looked at library documentation and I saw that ogr2ogr can do the job. It looks to me that this utility is based on the command line. How can I embed its functions in a C# script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the ogr2ogr command work? An easy one would be [to run it from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands). Otherwise you can use the C# SWIG bindings, if you can get these for your programming environment with PGeo support.

If you are using GDAL 1.x use [OGR_DS_CopyLayer](http://www.gdal.org/1.11/ogr/ogr__api_8h.html#a628d34530517b618696c97b73de31df7)/[OGRDataSource::CopyLayer](http://www.gdal.org/1.11/ogr/classOGRDataSource.html#a42dc7f7f538cd4f083af350722fe53ae) (or whatever it is called in the C# bindings). Or if you are using GDAL 2.x, use [GDALDatasetCopyLayer](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_8h.html#ab6af8f62727c70bc767086fc5c0daf9c).

The idea is you open a PGeo dataset/layer, create/open a shapefile dataset, then copy the layer(s) (i.e. shapefile) between the two.

Comment: I managed to get it to work with the command line but I would like to use C# bindings. I manage to create something with OGR.Driver.CreateDataSource but I can't see any output. When should I use Copy Layer? On the Extracted data Source? and after that How does the output path need to be set? Assuming I want to test the function output locally on my C drive?